# FB GraphAPI /media query always returning empty array

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am calling FB graph api to retrieve media from instagram feed but always returning an empty array. My access token has all 30 permissions allocated to it so I'm lost as to what is going wrong. Is there something I need to do between my instagram and facebook app to allow results to be returned?

graph.facebook.com/v8.0/17841411827658255/media?access_token=

Comment: Are you talking about a business/creator account, or just a normal user account?

Comment: Hiya, business account friend.

Comment: Did you connect your IG account with a Facebook page?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started ?